# how to start vector animation in android studio by kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, vector

i have some xml with vector drawings in android studio. I need some help. How to show them by animation on mainActivity in Android Studio by kotlin. hello_android.xml is the main animation file. Result should look like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDx1S.png). All other vector files are on this [site](https://habr.com/ru/articles/347918/)

**hello_android.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/enabled"
        android:drawable="@drawable/hello_android_enabled"
        android:state_enabled="true"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/disabled"
        android:drawable="@drawable/hello_android_disabled"/>

    <transition
        android:drawable="@drawable/hello_android_waving"
        android:fromId="@id/enabled"
        android:toId="@id/disabled"/>

    <transition
        android:drawable="@drawable/hello_android_stay_calm"
        android:fromId="@id/disabled"
        android:toId="@id/enabled"/>
</animated-selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the small Example of how you can set the animation selector to a view. You can typically set it to layout background.

```
val animatedSelectorDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.hello_android) as AnimatedStateListDrawableCompat
            imageView.background = animatedSelectorDrawable
            imageView.isEnabled = true
```